# AddEventListener isn't working, hard-coded works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

this is pretty odd. I'm trying to add event listener but it doesn't work though hard-coding it to the html is working.

Here's my code -

```
        <script src="js/dynamo.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
        <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            Dynamo.intilize();
            Dynamo.loadAndReplace("js/index.json");
        };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <main>
          <a href="test">tet</a>
```

The Dynamo.intilize function =

```
var Dynamo = {
    __elements: document.getElementsByTagName("*"),
    intilize: function() {
        var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            var link = links[i].attributes[0].value;
            if (link.match(/^https?/) === null) {  
                console.log(links[i]);
                links[i].addEventListener("mouseover",
                        function(event) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            alert('event');
                            //Dynamo.loadAndReplace('js/' + link + '.json');
                           // history.pushState(null, null, links[i].href);
                        }
                , false);
            }
        }
    },
    manipulateValue: function(elem, manipulation) {
        for (var i = 0; i < elem.attributes.length; i++) {
            elem.setAttribute(elem.attributes[i].name, manipulation(elem.attributes[i].value));
        }
    },
    replace: function(str, match, replacement) {
        return str.replace(new RegExp('\{\{' + match + '\}\}', "g"), replacement);
    },
    loadAndReplace: function(json) {

        $.getJSON(json, function(data) {

            var keys = Object.keys(data);

            for (var i = 0; i < Dynamo.__elements.length; i++) {
                if (Dynamo.__elements[i].attributes.length !== 0) {
                    Dynamo.manipulateValue(Dynamo.__elements[i],
                            function(val) {
                                for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
                                    return val.replace('{{' + keys[j] + '}}', data[keys[j]]);
                                }
                            });
                } else {
                    for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
                        Dynamo.__elements[i].innerHTML = Dynamo.replace(Dynamo.__elements[i].innerHTML, keys[j], data[keys[j]]);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work and I don't know why, there are no errors, nothing. The if part *IS* working.

Comment: Are you sure it's `links[i].attributes[0].value` and not `links[i].getAttribute('href')`

Comment: I'm sure. I need the value, not the href

Comment: An anchor has no value, and that's not what you're getting ?

Comment: Most likely the condition is failing, either the regex check, or whatever value he's trying to get from the anchor.

Comment: The condition isn't failing and it isn't related to the name of the function ffs

Comment: There's no issue in the code presented, though I would question the wisdom of relying on the order of attributes instead of the name. If the condition isn't failing, then there's certainly no way for us to know what the issue is.

Comment: Define [But it doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/vtx6h5y3/)

Comment: ...and you should really provide more information right from the start, like what debugging you've done, and so on. If the condition isn't failing, then that would mean that removing all the code except for the calling `addEventListener` on the first link should also fail. Does it?

Comment: Well, I've tried adding a simple console.log after the if statement and there's an output, so it means that the if statement is working. The only thing that isn't working is the event listener. If I console.log(links[i]) inside the if statement I get <a href="test">tet</a>

Comment: Have you tried different event types? Is there any other code that you're leaving out? Any more deeply nested element that would stop propagation of the event?

Comment: @Yehonatan Is it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vtx6h5y3/)?? What we now need is `dynamo.js`. either `Dynamo` is `undefined` or it doesn't have any of those methods or they might be spelled incorrectly like @Pointy pointed out (*Which is the same as it doesn't have that method*).

Comment: I did. I've tried click which was the first one but it didn't work.
I'll Dynamo's code if you guys need it

Comment: Is Dynamo a 3rd party library, or is it your code?

Comment: @cookiemonster my code, TJ It is working there. And why would you -1 it guys? 0.o

Comment: I don't know why would someone do that, BTW, have you included `jQuery`?

Comment: `Dynamo.__elements[i].innerHTML =` You're destroying elements and replacing them with new ones that don't have handlers. *The DOM is not a string of HTML*.

Comment: Well [still seems to be working](http://jsfiddle.net/vtx6h5y3/2/)

Comment: ...yikes, you're doing it on elements fetched using `getElementsByTagName("*")`, which means you're doing it to *all* elements *(at least ones with no attributes)* and therefore doing it repeatedly for nested elements. That's about as bad as it gets. Probably good to take some time and learn the basics of DOM programming.

Comment: @TJ what kind of sorcery is this? And cookie, I'm trying my best, can you show me another way?

Comment: First you need to understand why you can't do that. When you fetch `getElementsByTagName("*")` you're getting all elements on the page. The first element is the root `<HTML>` element. So when you do `.innerHTML = ...` on that element, you're basically destroying all of its content, and building new content from the string that you provide *(which in this case happens to be the same string but with some characters replaced)*. That destroys and rebuilds the entire page. And because you do it on that collection, it does the same on the `head`, `body` and any other element with no attributes...

Comment: ...since your `if` statement is set up that way. So ultimately, what you need to do is replace occurrences of certain text in the DOM. That's a little bit of a complicated task, but you'll find solutions on how to do it if you search StackOverflow. Just keep in mind that any solution that is only a couple of lines is most likely wrong.

Comment: ok... Thanks @cookiemonster but how did it worked for TJ?

Comment: ...overall, it looks like you have a good, organized structure to your code, which is nice to see. It's just the DOM manipulation part that needs some attention. Any sort of manipulation should be approached as modifying individual nodes in a tree structure rather mass replacement of text.

Comment: ...@TJ's demo worked because the `getJSON` callback never runs, and that's where the faulty code is located. Here's his demo updated to run the problematic code: http://jsfiddle.net/vtx6h5y3/3/

Comment: @cookiemonster Are you sure? His code has the manipulation part

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. His demo has that code, but the `getJSON` request fails because `jsfiddle.net` doesn't respond to the `js/index.json` url for obvious reasons. So the callback is never invoked. So the faulty code never runs. So the elements are never destroyed. So the original handler remains and will be invoked when the event occurs.

Comment: Oh right... But still, your fiddle isn't working though his are working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59677/discussion-between-yehonatan-and-cookie-monster).